# neo4j cdi @inject proper startup

Tags: jakarta-ee, neo4j, osgi

I am having issues with Neo4J silently failing to persist nodes based on the scope of the class injecting the Neo4J database, therefore I tried wrapping the Neo4j database in the class below:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexManager;

@Named
@Singleton
public class GraphDatabaseMngr
{
    private static final String FILESYSTEM_DB = "target/dmsdb";
    private org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    /* below is for node indexing */
    private IndexManager indexManager;
    private Index<Node> index;

    public GraphDatabaseMngr()
    {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct()
    {
        setUp();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void preDestroy()
    {
        getGraphDb().shutdown();
    }

    public void setUp()
    {
        if (getGraphDb() == null)
        {
            setGraphDb(new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(FILESYSTEM_DB));
            setIndexManager(getGraphDb().index());
            setIndex(getIndexManager().forNodes("indexNodes"));
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is ok and whether injecting it in a @SessionScoped class is ok.

So far the class seems to be correctly injected but getting and adding nodes to the neo4j store doesn't work as expected with nodes not appearing stored but yet no error returned.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me, but I'd prefer to do init everything within the @PostConstruct method.

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class GraphDatabaseMngr
{
    private static final String FILESYSTEM_DB = "target/dmsdb";
    private org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    /* below is for node indexing */
    private IndexManager indexManager;
    private Index<Node> index;


    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct()
    {
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(FILESYSTEM_DB);
        indexManager = getGraphDb().index();
        index = indexManager.forNodes("indexNodes")
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void preDestroy()
    {
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

   // your getters
}
```

There should be no problem injecting this bean into other beans (request, session or whatever scoped) of your application. 
For diagnosing the problem of nodes not being stored: add some logging to the @PostConstruct/@PreDestroy methods to see that the lifecycle of this bean is ok (I'm quite sure it is). It seems me more to be a problem of missing transactions (but this should be reported by Neo4j) - can you verify that?

Comment: I can assure you no error was reported by Neo4j and the transaction executed correctly upon debugging and just changing the scope of parent bean from session to application made it magically work. No error or warning nothing given back. I finally gave up Neo4J as too unstable for my setup also noone gave me any support so guess Neo4J is not much used in web applications as mine.